# How to Export First 100 product using dataflow profile

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

How can i Export only first 100 products from magento using magento inbuilt data flow profile functionality. i want to export first products but there are 20000 products there on my store so i want to export products in bunch of 1000.Waiting for suggestion.

[image]

Comment: if those first 100 products sku (or name) are starting with same name like 9la9512-431,9la9512-432......,9la9512-530, you can use 9la9512- in sku field under export filters option

Comment: Since this is no programming specific issue, but about backend usage maybe http://magento.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask.

Comment: yes thank for responce @JürgenThelen, I also asking this question on it

Comment: No @DRAJI I don't want to export product using filter [link condition].I want to export based on condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by rewrite the core function getIdCollection() inside `Mage_Dataflow_Model_Batch_Abstract` class.

There is return all id collections, you can customize code there as you need it.

Currently return code as per following:

`return` $this->getResource()->getIdCollection($this), you can replace code as per following

```
//return $this->getResource()->getIdCollection($this);
        $idArray = array();
        foreach($this->getResource()->getIdCollection($this) as $key => $val){
            if($key < 100){
                $idArray[] = $val;
            }
        }
        return $idArray;
```

After Please check downloaded csv, don't see loaded records on popup window Hope this would help you!..